# How do I insert NULL values for blank fields when using JQuery Serialize?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, serialization

I have many forms that I am serializing.  The data is posted to either an insert.php page or update.php.

If a form input is left blank, I want to insert a NULL value into my database.  I'm using mySQL.

It seems like when a form is serialized, any fields that are left blank are sent as value of '' which does NOT insert as NULL into my db.

I can filter out empty inputs before serializing, but this isn't good when a record needs to be updated.

Here's a fiddle of a form that you can at least see that empty inputs are logged as "".

Any advice on how I can set those values to NULL instead?

jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/bynaK/

Comment: This is not about javascript - that's how html forms work. If you want to replace empty strings with null do that server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply at `php` side check if value is empty use instead null with `strlen(...) == 0 condition` ( as @PaulSpiegel mentioned in comment of this answer `empty` will consider that 0 is also empty and will write null to your db )  - http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php

```
// Example
$value = !strlen($_POST['value']) ? null:$_POST['value'];
// .. save in MySQL
```

Comment: `empty('0')` will return `true`. Use `strlen()` instead.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel but OP just need to save null in case of "" value of input so i mean `empty()` is what he need

Comment: But you also will convert `'0'` to `null`.

Comment: ah ok agree updating answer

Comment: thank you for taking the time to help me.  I did what you suggested, and it is working.  I really appreciate it.